# Configuring php desktop chrome for allowing it to connect to sql server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, exe, desktop-application

I wanted to convert my php application into desktop application to run it as an .exe file by just double clicking on it. For this I found many third party softwares like bamcompile,wapache,Php desktop chrome,etc. From these the most compatible and the one which fulfilled my requirements to accountable extent was php desktop chrome.The rest both had their drawbacks-

1.Bamcompile-It runs the application on commandline and does not show GUI,so I was not comfortable with that.

2.Wapache-It runs the application but it run it in Internet explorer browser so it cannot run the framework supported by my application.I need Google Chrome for that.

3.Php desktop chrome- This fulfills my requirement to a great extent but the problem is that it does not supports sql server database.I thought about using sql server as database because I don't want to install xampp/wamp on every machine where I want to use my application.I added the drivers needed for using sql server to php desktop/ext folder but  I am not finding the php.ini in php desktop application where  I can add extension to it.So it there any way that I would not have to install xampp/wamp or any other application on client machine to run my application.

Problem with converting the application into exe file is solved with php desktop. That means when I start only mysql from xampp my application runs perfectly fine ,there is no need to start apache for that.So now  I want to do something that can include my database as well in the php desktop chrome folder and supporting application into it as well.So that I don't need to start phpmyadmin always.Or is it possible to install only phpmyadmin/MySQL without xampp and if yes how to configure that?Because I installed that individually but I don't know why is it showing Access denied.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried to provide as much details as possible ,in case you need to know anything else,please let me know. I have tried all possible way please help me out.

Comment: Switching to SQLite3 is best option.

Answer (score -1):

Your need is quite exotic. Try phpinfo() in your application - then you will find where your php.ini is served from. That might put you on track. Another thing to try, if your database is not too big, SqlLite database in your project, because it is bundled with php and does not require a separate server.